# If equal to groups[*][0], where groups is array of tuples?

Tags: python

Say I have an array of tupels like this:

```
[('9a4591116d2c', 'production', None), ('a3270aa13595', 'production', '58cac003c0ed42196da3d50e'), ('puppetdb', 'production', 'test')]
```

I want to see if a value matches the first value of any of the tuples. Is there a quick way to do this something like:

```
if node in groups[*][0]
```

Comment: to clarify the `[*][0]` means "the first element of each tuple" correct?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yes sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest working alternative to `if node in groups[*][0]` would be

```
if node in (x[0] for x in groups):
    ...
```

but you could also do

```
if any(node == first for first, *_ in groups):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your list into a `numpy` array which has nicer slicing properties:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array(your_list_here)
>>> '9a4591116d2c' in A[:, 0]
True
```

It's unfortunate there isn't syntax like this in base python. :(